# Difference between a Java String UTF8 and String8?

Tags: java, equals

What is  difference between a String8(C++) and a String in Java ?

Comment: Java stores strings as UTF-16 (originally UCS-2) internally.

Comment: You mean `u8` in C++?

Comment: @fge Apparently [String8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd240126.aspx) is a real thing, as is [String16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd240127.aspx).

Comment: Java's Strings cannot be made to handle binary data, it makes a clear distinction (this is unlike a `char *` in C/C++ in this regard). No idea how `u8` and others handle that. In fact, no idea how you specify an encoding to write text in C++

Comment: @Powerlord yeah, and `String16` is misleading -- you cannot store Unicode code points outside the BMP with it, at least not with a single... What... `char8_t`? Nor can you do that with Java, which is why you have all of these `codePoint*()` methods on `String` and `Character` (and `Character.toChars()`)

Comment: as example in aapt ( Android Asset Packaging Tool) uses internal String8 is a String8 a simple char array ?

Comment: @sader1994 are you sure this is C++ "proper"? I see no mention of `String8` anywhere I look except at the site @Powerlord provides

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-mr0-release/libs/utils/String8.cpp

Comment: Uh, OK, doesn't tell much; in the meanwhile [this](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.fr/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html) may help you for understanding the Java side of things

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell:

```
 Property                    java.lang.String    android::String8
 ================================================================
 language                    Java                C++
 Unicode                     yes                 yes
 char width                  16                  8
 encoding                    UTF-16              UTF-8
 mutability                  immutable           mutable
 bunch of file path methods  no                  yes
 attitude to Darwin          indifferent         annoyed (line 47)
```

They are both Unicode string types; the similarities seem to end there.

Answer (score 0):

The more important difference is Java String consumes aproximately twice the memory than String8 and other alternatives for the same text.

Also Java String is inmutable: so you cannot modify its contents and this have some good... and... some very bad implications (although you have StringBuilder and other alternatives).

Comment: That a string consumes twice the memory is not correct for recent versions of Java, which will encode the string in a byte[] instead of a char[] when the characters can be encoded as iso-8859-1 (latin1).